# How to add ng-class based on multiple variable comparison?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-class

My select dropdown, needs the class of `btn-success` if 2 variables form a JSON object `!= null`.

What I've tried so far which isn't working, basically if `term.tag` and `term.id` are not null, add the class `btn-success` to the select.

This is inside of an ng-repeat `term in terms` is the JSON data.

```
<select ng-class="{ 'btn-success': term.tag != null && term.id != null }">
    <option value="companies">companies</option>
    <option value="news">news</option>
    <option value="people">people</option>
    <option value="products">products</option>
</select>
```

How would you go about this?

Comment: You should create a function in your controller to update a variable. Too much logic in your view is a bad thing.

Comment: Depends on what your term.tag is. Try just `term.tag && term.id`.

Comment: isherwood is right. Create a controller function and have it return the class you want right into ng-class.

Comment: @dfsq oh thanks! Yeah that is better, do you want to post an answer? Btw I found this which reads better too `<select ng-class="term.tag && term.id ? 'btn-success' : 'btn-default'">` To left of : is if true, to right of : is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your HTML to something like this:

```
<select ng-class="getButtonClass()">
```

And add a function in your controller:

```
$scope.getButtonClass = function() {
    if (term.tag && term.id) {
        return 'btn-success';
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I could see that working for 1 example, however I have several hundred widgets which all contain the same select and generated on the page via an `ng-repeat term in terms`. Seems like there may be more involved in that case?

Comment: You'd probably pass in scope or some other indicator.

Comment: Oh yeah thanks! like... `<select ng-class="getButtonClass(term.tag, term.user_id)">`